# Regex value.match() in Google Refine

Tags: openrefine

I am trying to use create a column B in Google Refine based on another column A.

If column A contains text "X", "Y" **or** "Z", then column B will show 1, else will show 0.

My logic was:

1. using value.replace() to replace "X" with "Y"
2. then replace "Y" with "Z"
3. then use value.contains() to check if "Z" is contained.
   which will be: if((value.replace('X','Y').replace('Y','Z')).contains('Z'),1,0)

But is there a direct way of using value.match(regex) to reach the goal?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `.*[XYZ].*` as the regex?

Comment: Hi William, I used if(value.contains(/discount|offer|sale/), 1, 0) finally, it says no syntax error but the total row count for 1 or 0 are not right. Idk where Im wrong. But thank you for ur response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex-patterns with contains()](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions) using slashes like this:

```
value.contains(/[XYZ]/)
```

So in your case

```
if(value.contains(/[XYZ]/), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Hi Clauswer, I tried using this expression. But it became that the new column shows 1 for all cells. Then I used if(value.contains(/discount|offer|sale/), 1, 0), it says no syntax error but the total row count for 1 or 0 are not right. Idk where Im wrong. But thank you anyways!